# Marketing Cloud - Synchronization

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

ow to know if how long does Marketing Cloud unsubscribe status change for a specific contact? Is there a settings wherein we can input synchronization of the data from Salesforce to Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synchronised data extensions use “poll times”, to determine how often data is synchronised. You can have this at a minimum of 15 mins, so in your case unsubscribes in the crm are reflected with 15 minutes.

The Unsubscribes are held in the account object (HasOptedOutOfEmail - `boolean`).

To modify this, go into the object

- Contact Builder > Data Sources > Click on the Salesforce Icon
- Click on the contact object
- Click on Configuration settings in the left corner
  [image]
- Here you can you your polling schedule and adjust as required.

[image]